# ScrumDesk TFS Integration Error - Project Does Not Contain Integrations

Tags: tfs, scrum

I am trying to get ScrumDesk ([http://www.scrumdesk.com/](http://www.scrumdesk.com)) working with integration to Team Foundation Server.  All software is running on a single system.  When I start the ScrumDesk Synchronization Hub, I get errors:

1:  Unable to create integration with TFS2010

2:  Connection 'TFSSync' will be stopped because it does not contain integrations.  Configure, please, them in ScrumDesk.

I have a working connection between the ScrumDesk client software and the ScrumDesk database on the server.  I have created a project and added sprints in ScrumDesk, and done my best to try every combination of adding those sprints in TFS as well.  The documentation for this tool is not clear on what to do for several of the steps.  I have added the synchronization information in the ScrumDesk client under project properties as well, but that step does not display the project name which may hint at a problem on that end as well as in the Synchronization Hub.

Anyone out there actually have this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did you check SDHub category in Event log? Send messages to support@scrumdesk.com
2. Run Hub as administrator (right click, Run as Administrator). Administrator privileges  are necessary for using message queues used for communication with TFS.
3. Pair TFS project details with ScrumDesk project using ScrumDesk client application on Project/Integrations tab

Comment: This is still on my to-do list Dusan - I'm not ignoring that e-mail.  Build 2011 has seriously affected my amount of free time.

Comment: I have lost the ability to test this (no longer have access to the server that caused the problem).  I am going to mark this as answered since you did provide the tools needed to debug the problem.